# Выразить уважение - чему-то или к чему-то, как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

"Выразить уважение к его прошлым работам" или "выразить уважение его прошлым работам"? Как написать правильно и почему?

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Выразить ему уважение за прошлые работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предмет или субъект *уважения* всегда связан с этим словом через предлог (*иметь, испытывать* уважение **к кому** или **к чему**), однако *выразить* это уважение (здесь: к работам) можно как самому человеку (*выразить, высказать что-либо* **кому**), так и *публично* - в обоих случаях без предлога. В данном случае *не* говорится, *кому именно* или перед кем *выражено* уважение "к его работам", остаётся только предложная связка уважения с предметом уважения:

> Выразить уважение **к** его прошлым работам...

Резюме: *выразить* **кому**; *уважение* **к кому**, **к чему**.

Answer (score 1):

Выразить (проявить) уважение - **к** чему/кому-либо,

отда(ва)ть дань уважения - чему/кому-либо.

[ПРИНОСИТЬ ДАНЬ УВАЖЕНИЯ](https://phraseology.academic.ru/9768/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> *кому.* Книжн. Офиц. Оказывать должное внимание, уважение и т. п. кому-либо за какие-либо заслуги. *Чичиков уже хотел было выразиться в
>   таком духе, что, наслышась о добродетели и редких свойствах души его,
>   почёл долгом принести лично дань уважения* (Гоголь. Мёртвые души).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

УВАЖЕНИЕ

> **1.** Почтение, почтительное отношение, основанное на признании чьих-л. заслуг, качеств, достоинств и т.п. *У. к родителям, к старшим.
>   Питать к кому-л. глубокое у. Я делаю это исключительно из уважения к
>   вам, к вашим заслугам. Этот человек достоин величайшего уважения. Он
>   пользуется всеобщим уважением. Относиться друг к другу с взаимным
>   (обоюдным) уважением.* **2.** Уважительное отношение к законам,
>   порядкам, правилам, интересам и чувствам других людей и т.п. *У. к
>   закону. У. к Конституции. У. к чувствам верующих. В чужом доме надо с
>   уважением относиться к порядкам, установленным хозяевами.*